# How to use ArcGis ESRI maps in angular

Tags: angular, esri, arcgis-js-api

Can someone help me how to plot latitude and longitudes on esri maps in angular please?

Comment: How are you getting the coordinates?, what is the source?

Comment: am getting the coordinates from MongoDB,@cabesuon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, you need to include the ArcGIS library in your angular project. For that you have two options:

1. using `@arcgis/webpack-plugin`, or
2. using `esri-loader`

This that I mentions plus both options are well documented in the ArcGIS documents [ArcGIS Docs - Using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript with Angular](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/angular/).

Once you get your project running, you are ready to take the next step.

I am still not quite sure how are you retrieving the data. So the general answer in the API context would be:

1. If your data is in GeoJSON format, you can use `GeoJSONLayer` ([ArcGIS Docs - GeoJSONLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GeoJSONLayer.html))
2. If your data is in CSV format, you can use `CSVLayer` ([ArcGIS Docs - CSVLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-CSVLayer.html))
3. If your data is in KML format you can use `KMLLayer` ([ArcGIS Docs - KLLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-KMLLayer.html))
4. Finally, the general answer would be to use `FeatureLayer` and `source` attribute. The process in this case is to retrieve the data create the features (probably using `esri/Graphic`, `esri/geometry/Point` and `esri/geometry/SpatialReference`), and then add it to the layer using `applyEdits` method.

One great thing of ArcGIS API (and ESRI's product in general) is that it has great documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot...i will follow the steps which you mentioned as well as documentation...

Comment: Glad it helps you!!